# Installing Theme from uploaded file. Not uploaded theme?

Tags: themes, ftp, local-installation

I'm totally new to WordPress, and I'm trying to upload theme from Upload Theme in themes section.

While uploading theme it is asking for "FTP server access credentials", but I'm working on localhost and I haven't set any credentials for that.

I'm trying to upload *Bizgrowth* theme which I'm downloaded from https://wordpress.org/themes/bizgrowth/ this site.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you developing on Mac or PC?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the permissions locally in a UNIX environment:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /usr/share/wordpress
```

Also perhaps:

```
chown -R nobody:nobody /path/to/wordpress
```

Also try setting the FTP creds in the wp-config.php file:

```
define( 'FTP_USER', 'username' ); 
define( 'FTP_PASS', 'password' ); 
define( 'FTP_HOST', 'ftp.example.org:21' );
```

Use "admin" or "root" for user and leave the password blank.

Comment: Is this permission to main WordPress folder or to downloaded theme folder, because I already set permission to main folder

Comment: Did you set it recursively? I would set it to the theme folder to be sure

Comment: Also you can manually set FTP permissions in wp-config.php, see my edit above.

Comment: After setting FTP permissions, it gives an error : Failed to connect to FTP Server localhost/wordpress:21